# Evento onclick() para alterar o texto de um botão (play / pause)

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho essa div no meu html e queria fazer com que ao clicar no botão play trocar o texto para pause e ao clicar novamente trocar para play.

```js
var buttonControl = document.querySelector('#control');
var playNameControl = document.createTextNode('play');
var pauseNameControl = document.createTextNode('pause');

buttonControl.onclick = function control(){
    if(buttonControl.value = 'play'){
        buttonControl.innerHTML = '';
        buttonControl.appendChild(pauseNameControl);
        buttonControl.setAttribute('value','pause');
    }
    else{
        buttonControl.innerHTML = '';
        buttonControl.appendChild(playNameControl);
        buttonControl.setAttribute('value','play');
    }
}
```

```html
   <div class="botoes">
        <button id="control">play</button>
   </div>
```

Só funciona para o primeiro click. Como começa com play ao clicar ele ta mudando pra pause mas ao clicar novamente não há mudanças mais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinceramente eu acho que vc complicou as coisas com esse seu código, então preferi nem aproveita-lo na resposta...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

Veja que é basicamente um `if/else`, que troca o `.textContent` do `btn` no `click`

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

function troca() {
    if (btn.textContent === "play") {
        btn.textContent = "pausa";
        btn.value = "pausa"
    } else {
        btn.textContent = "play";
        btn.value = "play"
    }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', troca)
```

```html
<button id="btn">play</button>
```